# How can one change an entire document to use bold font?

Tags: fonts, bold

I see many posts in how to changes the font and font size, but none for changing the default font for a document to bold font. I believe this is called changing the font series. The approach in http://www.forkosh.com/pstex/latexcommands.htm (obtained by random Googling) looks like it should work, but doesn't do anything when I stick it in the preamble. Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place.

```
\fontencoding{T1}
\fontfamily{garamond}
\fontseries{m}
\fontshape{it}
\fontsize{12}{15}
\selectfont
```

There is also some discussion [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=3994).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could redefine `\seriesdefault` in your document preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{\bfdefault}
```

`\bfdefault` means the value `bx` by default, as font parameter, you also could have used this in the redefinition directly.

```
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{bx}
```

So, with `bx` as the default, either way, the default weight of the document font is like if you would have written`\bfseries` for some text. But with the redefinition above, every time `\normalfont` is called, bold weight is used. Also already at the start of the document.

Note, you still could switch to normal weight by `\mdshape` or `\textmd`. If you would like to prevent normal weight at all, you could redefine normal weight commands. It would be a bit strange, but you could decide that, such as by:

```
\renewcommand{\mddefault}{bx}
```

which would turn text even after using`\mdseries` to bold.

To the code in your question:

- It doesn't work because you used `m` (medium) instead of `bx` (bold extended). This would have worked:

  ```
  \fontseries{bx}
  \selectfont
  ```
- Even then it would just work where you placed it in the text, not as default. The next call of `\normalfont`, which could even be implicit, would remove the effect of these commands. That's also the reason why it does not seem to work if you placed it in the preamble, since `\begin{document}` causes switching back to default font.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what you mean by "\bfdefault means bx by default, you also could have used this in the redefinition directly". What is "bx"? And this goes in the preamble, right?

Comment: You mean you could write `\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{bx}` instead? BTW, would you care to remark on why the method in the link above doesn't work?

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes - I extended my answer. `bx` is like a simple text value for the argument, meaning a font parameter. And I explained why the original code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Did you mean to write `\fontseries{bx}\selectfont` at the end? And I meant that the listed command changed nothing at all, just as an example. I just tried `\fontseries{bx}\selectfont` and it didn't work either.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Yes, `\fontseries{bx}\selectfont`. Id didn't work, because you used it in the preamble. `\begin{document}` causes switching back to default font. Also appended to the answer now.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you need to call it after \begin{document}? In other words, not in the preamble. I would say "\begin{document} causes switching back to default font." in your answer. You wrote "since the document later starts with normal, default font", which is less clear, at least to me.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: Yes, it would work after `\begin{document}`. Until a command or environment would call `\fontseries` or `\normalfont`, which could be hidden.