# Document where all the text and mathematics shows in bold

Tags: bold

I would like to make a document where all the text and mathematics shows in bold.  How can I construct a command to do so in my style file.

Have done

```
\newcommand\bolden[1]{{\boldmath\bfseries#1}}
```

but this works only with argumunts, not for whole document.  It would be good to be able to switch this on and off.

Comment: You must propose at least one M(not?)WE showing what you have tried...

Comment: What ??? M(not?)WE ?  Write proper English.

Comment: see [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Why do you have to complicate a simple question and answer !

Comment: A minimal working example to do what ?

Comment: Have you looked at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41754/how-can-one-change-an-entire-document-to-use-bold-font and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25686/how-to-make-all-math-equations-bold-by-default

Comment: Have found the second link helpful with the command `\boldmath`.  Is there something similar for text that I can switch on and off ?

Comment: just use `\bfseries\boldmath`  after `\begin{document}` no need for any definition

Comment: Could I switch them off at some point within the document?

Comment: @Raksh, requesting a MWE makes it easier for all of us: just copy, compile and improve your code. // In Latex most of the time you can obtain the same or similar typesetting in different ways ... a MWE tells exactly which route you've chosen. // BTW, presenting MWE's not only is good style, respecting this community, but, as far as I remember, is also requested and reminded during sign-up. // So, help us helping you also reduces comments considerably ;-) // Thank you

Comment: yes of course (but your title implies that is not needed) `\mdseries\unboldmath`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\newcommand\bolden{\boldmath\bfseries}
\newcommand\unbolden{\unboldmath\mdseries}
```

Are the non-argument versions to enter bold and non-bold.

Comment: Worth knowing. I was going to suggest fooling TeX by re-labeling the Bold fonts as Regular, using a font editor (if not using `fontspec`) or simply defining the fonts to load the bold file names as if they were regular (probably works with `fontspec`). Amazed that there is a way to do it that does not involve brute force.

Comment: @rallg you are amazed that latex has a command to select bold??

Comment: I never use bold (I write fiction, not math). I was aware of bold commands, but did not imagine that there was a way to do it "globally" instead of for small portions. Did not seem like something anyone would ever want to do.

Comment: @rallg you (almost) never want to do it, but all commands will affect the whole document if you don't restrict them, not because affecting the whole document is a good idea, just because that's the way it works. You might not have bold but even novelists might use italic and if you put `\itshape` after begin document, your whole novel is italic.